# How can I simulate the LifeCircuit 12 rep set on a non-electronic workout machine?

Tags: exercise-equipment

I enjoyed the LifeCircuit computerized strength equipment, which apparently do not exist anymore.  How can I simulate that 12 rep set that those machines featured on a typical non-computerized workout machine at say Planet Fitness.  The LifeCircuit set had the exerciser lift at 75% of his max on the first rep, 80% on the second, 90% on the third, 100% on the next 6 reps, 90% on the 10th, 80% on the 11th and 70% on the last rep.  I'm pretty sure those percentages were not based on someone's 1 rep max.  If they were not based on someone's 1 rep max, which I assume they weren't, how can I translate these percentages or quantities on the LifeCircuit 12 rep set to percentages of my personal 1 rep max?  In other words, how do I simulate that LifeCircuit set on conventional machines?

Comment: Those definitely aren't going to be based on a one-two max. If you doing 6 of them it's no longer a one-rep max weight. However, the machine would automatically ramp up and ramp down the weight during the set? So every set was like a warm-up, workout, and back down?

Comment: Yes, it’s called pyramid-style training.  These machines were the best ever made, no comparison to the garbage that they make today.